# i want to make the image center

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I am creating a loading logo for splash screen.[animation looks exactly like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6j7Q/2/).so when I tried this code but my logo isn't positioned center as I wanted and also the logo is going down as the device length is increasing[it is looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqxs2.png).[supposed to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzQfD.png).i am using ionic4/angular8.

```css
ion-content{
--background:yellow;
}
.tree {
    left: 0;    
    right: 10%;
    margin:0 auto;
    top:50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
    position: relative;
}
.tree > div {
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background: yellow;
top: 0;
left: 0;
-webkit-animation-name: hello;
-webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 animation-name: hello;
animation-duration: 5s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.tree img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
@keyframes hello {
    0% {
        height: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        height: 0%;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes hello {
    0% {
        height: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        height: 0%;
    }
}
```

```html
<ion-content>
<div class="tree">
    <div></div>
    <img src="logo.svg" />
</div>
<ion-content>
```

Comment: class="text-center" doesn't helps?

Comment: it helped but when the device length is increasing the image is going down. the images what I provided is taken from iphone4 only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use margin: 0 auto

```
.tree {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use flexbox to solve this (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Playing around with the height which is currently using 80vh (view height) you could determine the position vertically. which is different when using another type of device (screen height)

```css
.tree {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 80vh;
        }
    
    .tree > div {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: #fff;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        -webkit-animation-name: hello;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        animation-name: hello;
        animation-duration: 5s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    
    .tree img {
        max-width: 300px;
    }
    
    @keyframes hello {
        0% {
            height: 100%;
        }
        100% {
            height: 0%;
        }
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes hello {
        0% {
            height: 100%;
        }
        100% {
            height: 0%;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="tree">
    <div></div>
    <img src="http://www.colourbox.com/preview/4221089-363386-green-vector-tree-nature-symbol.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple center the div

```html
<ion-content>
<center>
<div class="tree">
    <div></div>
    <img src="logo.svg" />
</div>
</center>
<ion-content>
```

Comment: [center tags are obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) and should not be used, use css instead

Answer (score -2):

```css
ion-content{
--background:yellow;
}
.tree {
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-50px;
    margin-left:-50px;
}

.tree img {
    max-width: 100px;
}
@keyframes hello {
    0% {
        height: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        height: 0%;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes hello {
    0% {
        height: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        height: 0%;
    }
}
```

```html
<ion-content>
<div class="tree">
   <div class="loader-img">
    <img src="http://www.colourbox.com/preview/4221089-363386-green-vector-tree-nature-symbol.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
<ion-content>
```